# How to remove elements from a list with lambda based on another list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have List of file Paths: .

```
List<Path> filePaths; //e.g. [src\test\resources\file\15\54\54_exampleFile.pdf]
```

`54` above refers to file ID

I then obtain a `Set` of `String` Ids which my application can handle as follows:

```
Set<String> acceptedIds = connection.getAcceptedIDs(); //e.g. elements [64, 101, 33]
```

How can I use Java 8 lambdas to `filter` out all elements in `filePaths` that do not contain any of the acceptable Ids that are contained in `acceptedIds` collection Set.

In other words, I would like to retain in `filePaths` only the paths that have ids which are in `acceptedIds` set. For example, 54 is not in the above list so is removed.

```
filePaths.stream().filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can we rely on the immediate parent directory being named with the  ID?

Comment: filePaths.removeIf(p -> !acceptedIds.contains(p.getPath())

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most efficient way is to extract the ID from the path, then attempt to find it in the Set, making each filter execute in constant time, ie `O(1)` giving an overall `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of paths:

```
filePaths.stream()
  .filter(p -> acceptedIds.contains(p.getParent().getFileName().toString()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the reverse approach is done, where each `acceptedIds` is searched for in the path (as in other answers), each filter is `O(m*k)`, where `m` is the number of `acceptedIds` and `k` is the average Path length, giving an overall `O(n * m * k)`, which will perform very poorly for even moderate sizes of collections.

Comment: how should I `trim()` the ids for whitespaces when extracting ?

Comment: Where is the whitespace? In the path, eg `"src\test\resources\file\15\54 \54_exampleFile.pdf"` (directory name is `"54 "` - with a space), or in the values stored in `acceptedIds`?

Comment: To be efficient, the values in the Set should be trimmed once (ideally within `connection.getAcceptedIDs()`), but to do it in your method, `acceptedIds = acceptedIds.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: `connection.getAcceptedIDs()` is getter of my connection model. So should I return from that method `return acceptedIds.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toSet());` is that what you mean? I would prefer to trim as you say within getter

Comment: It would be better to trim as the values are added to the set; you want to to be a one-time effort if possible.

Comment: I agree, they're being added to set with `Spring EL`,  `<constructor-arg value="#{'${file.specifiedIds}'.split(',')}"/>`. I couldn't see a way of trimming with EL. Do you know if trim can be used with split in that EL

Comment: @user2781389 easy - just trim them during the split! `<constructor-arg value="#{'${file.specifiedIds}'.trim().split(' *, *')}"` :)

Answer (score 4):

You could write:

```
filePaths.stream()
         .filter(p -> acceptedIds.stream().anyMatch(id -> p.toString().contains(id)))
         .collect(toList());
```

This filters each path such that at least one of the `acceptedIds` is contained in the string representation of the path. You might want to implement something better than `contains` here, depending on your use-case (matching the beginning of the filename for example).

[`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) is an operation that determines if at least one element matches the given predicate.

Note that this answer does not make any assumption about the path to filter out elements. If you can safely say that in each path, the parent directory is named with the id, you should definitely go with @Bohemian answer, for performance reason.

Comment: `p.toString().contains(id)` implies `"54".contains("4")` or `"543".contains("4")` I doubt that this matches the OP’s intentions.

Comment: @Holger I agree, that's why I said he might want to implement something better (like matching the beginning of the filename).

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
List removeMissing(List l1, List l2) {
    List ret = l1.stream()
        .filter(o -> l2.contains(o)) //Keep if object o satisfies the condition "l2 contains a reference to this object"
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file name structure is constant, I'd use a regex first to extract the number, and then will check if it is among the desired ids.

```java
final Set<String> acceptedIds = ...
// Matches the number of the file, concluded with the underscore
final Pattern extractor = Pattern.compile("\.*(?<number>\d+)_")
filePaths.stream().filter( path -> {
    final Matcher m = extractor
        .matcher(path.getFileName().toString());
    m.find();
    return acceptedIds.contains(m.group("number"));
})
...
```